# Why is my a:hover css working differently in Firefox?

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, cross-browser

I cannot figure this out. I HAVE DONE RESEARCH so please, no comments about me doing more research. Also, I am a noob, so be nice ;)

Here's my site: http://library.skybundle.com/

Hover your mouse over the two black rectangles in the main blue nav bar (header area). The a:hover should make the color change to a gray. The ISSUE is that in Chrome, this looks perfect. But, in Firefox, the padding-right isn't long enough or something, so there is always a small black rectangle at the far right side of the "Educational Courses" button (this will only be visible when hovering your cursor over the button). In other words, the gray box doesn't go all the way to the right-side end of the button area upon mouse hover. I just don't understand why this looks and works great in Chrome, but bugs out in Firefox...

Believe me when I say I have tried everything I can to fix it using Firebug in Firefox. If you play around with it using an editor in your browser, you will see that if you try to make the padding longer for Firefox, it pops the whole button down onto a new line. So to fix THAT problem, you must make the container wider, but then the original problem comes back. It's a circle of problems and I'm sure one of you geniuses out there will see a simple solution that I am missing.

Please help. Thanks!

**EDIT :**

Here's my JSFiddle and code. Notice how it looks great in Chrome but not in Firefox?

http://jsfiddle.net/S4st8/

HTML:

```
<div id="navigation">
  <div id="navigation-inner">
    <div id="page-nav">
      <div id="primary-nav">
        <ul id="top-menu">
          <li id="li-left"><a href="#">Product Training Videos</a></li>
          <li id="li-right"><a href="#">Educational Courses</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#navigation {
  background: url(http://library.skybundle.com/wp-content/themes/business-services/library/styles/colour-images/mu-nav.jpg) repeat-x;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  height: 40px;
  width: 100%;
}

#navigation-inner {
  margin: 0px auto;
  padding: 0px;
  height: 48px;
  width: 960px;
}

#page-nav {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  height: 40px;
  width: 960px;
}

div#primary-nav {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

ul#top-menu {
  margin: -5px 0.325em 0 0.325em;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 0;
  z-index: 100;
  top: 0;
  left: 3em;
  width: 367px;
}

ul#top-menu li {
  line-height: 3em;
  list-style-type: none;
  height: 49px;
  background-color: #2C2C2C;
  float: left;
}

li#li-right {
  list-style-position: inside;
  border-left: 2px solid #5E5E5E;
}

ul#top-menu li a {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 11pt;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 15px 10px 16px 10px;
  color: #ffffff;
}

ul#top-menu li a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  width: auto;
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #505354;
  padding: 15px 10px 17px 10px;
}
```

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link 
to the site that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value
to future visitors once the problem is solved. Posting a 
[Short, Self Contained, Correct Example (SSCCE)](http://www.sscce.org/) 
that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, 
see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to
it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Comment: @j08691 OK Thanks, I didn't realize this. But good point, let me grab some code to post real fast. Thanks

Comment: I believe you. Now, fix it!

Comment: I would check your HTML as well, I saw bad code like this: <div class="skone-half"></p>, <div class="skone-half sklast"></p> and <p style="text-align: center;"></div></p>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

its because **a** tags (anchor tags) have a default **display** property of **inline**

due to **[CSS Box Model](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box_model)** you would need to adjust your padding and set the anchor tags display property to display:block;

the display block allows the anchor tag to fill the whole space of the LI tag

change **ul#top-menu li a** to this:

```
ul#top-menu li a{
    color: #FFFFFF;        
    font-size: 11pt;
    font-weight: bold;

    display: block; /* add this */
    padding: 0 10px; /* add this */
}
```

the CSS Box Model adds the content + padding + border + margin

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box_model

Comment: Perfect! It fixed it. I changed the padding to

"padding: 1px 10px 0px 10px;"

to make it look really good.

Comment: nice.. glad its fixed! :)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this CSS rule:

```
li#li-right {
  border-left: 2px solid #5E5E5E;
  list-style-position: inside;
}
```

Dropping `list-style-position: inside` seems to fix your issue in Firefox (and still works in Chrome), but I haven't tested the implications in other browsers.  The CSS rule is documented [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/list-style-position).

Comment: You are right. list-style: none inside none; is the fix.

Firefox and or other browsers aply their own 'spacing' ...

Comment: This worked as well, but I think @Jonathan's answer is a little bit more stable. I appreciate it, everyone!

Answer (score 1):

The reason why : browsers apply their own css if you don't specify it. Firefox added the space for your bullet (somehow)

FF :

- list-style-image none
- list-style-position  outside
- list-style-type          disc

GooChrome :

- list-style-image: none;
- list-style-position: inside;
- list-style-type:   none;

User JasonSperske gave you a fixing solution,
i invite you to RESET your css.

PS. in the meantime, you are invited to see : https://stackoverflow.com/help AND  http://sscce.org/

Reading and understanding those pages will give you few reputations points